# Criar uma referência de uma classe a partir de uma variável

Tags: c#

não sei se expliquei corretamente no título e peço que me corrijam.

Eu estou fazendo um sistema simples de um banco em C# por orientação de objetos seguindo a apostila da **caelum** [(Link da apostila)](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-csharp-orientacao-objetos/classes-e-objetos/) e também fazendo algumas alterações com base em meus conhecimentos. Eu gostaria de fazer um sistema de cadastro de referências, abaixo o exemplo da criação de um conta no banco:

```
private void buttonCadatro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   Conta c1 = new Conta();

   c1.numero = 1;
   c1.Saldo = 100;

}
```

E abaixo as declarações de variáveis da classe **conta.cs**

```
public int numero;
public Double Saldo;
```

E questão é o seguinte, eu gostaria de fazer que a cada vez que ele que no **botão cadastra** seja criada uma nova conta, por exemplo: c2 com número = 2, c3 com número = 3. Ou seja se eu falo da conta com o .numero = 3, ele já entende que é a referência **c3**;

Eu também gostaria de fazer com que a conta 1 transferisse R$ 10 para a conta 2 sem usar os **c1** e **c2**, apenas do uso dos **.numero**

Espero que tenham entendido, e como disse antes, corrijam meus erros.

Comment: qual o banco de dados usado?

Comment: Por enquanto não estou usando banco de dados, apenas estou treinando mesmo. Quando fechar o programa será apagada a memória.

Comment: Sugestão de nome de propriedade Saldo para _saldo quando for privado e Saldo quando tiver modificador de acesso, exemplo: public double Saldo{ get; set}

Comment: em caso do nome, você precisa criar uma forma de visualizar os dados e depois uma leitura, então adiciona uma função na criação do nome que seria C + Count(+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vai ser difícil você lidar com transações sem ter um banco de dados. Mas digamos que você já tenha carregado o seu banco:

Você pode adicionar no seu main uma Lista:

`public List<Conta> contas = new List<Conta>();`

```
public class Conta
{
    public int numero;
    public Double Saldo;
}    

private void buttonCadatro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contas.add(new Conta()
            {
               numero = 1; 
               Saldo = 100;
            }); 
}
```

Você pode criar um evento de transferencia:

```
private void buttonTransfere(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Transfere(1,2,300); //transfere 300 reais da conta 1 para a conta 2
}

private bool Transfere(int idContaOrigem, int idContaDestino, double valor){
    if(contas.ElementAtOrDefault(idContaOrigem) != null && contas.ElementAtOrDefault(idContaDestino) != null){
        if(contas[idContaOrigem].Saldo >= valor){
            contas[idContaOrigem].Saldo -=  valor ;
            contas[idContaDestino].Saldo +=  valor ;
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Lembrando que não é a maneira mais correta de se fazer, já fiz esse curso e mais futuramente terá uma melhor explicação sobre, mas já resolve seu problema. De qualquer forma vou editar minha resposta mais tarde com uma melhor solução.

Comment: Consegui resolver a maior parte do problema. Vou abrir um novo tópico para se adequar mais com a minha situação.